# Using recode in R to change observation name

Tags: r, string, recode

I'm trying to use "recode" from the car package for the first time. The code seems simple enough, and I would like to rename observations that are "pm25_rank" to "PM2.5", however I keep getting an error saying there is an unused arguement.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

```
dat<-c("pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank","pm25_rank")

test1<-recode(dat, c("PM2.5" = "pm25_rank"))
```

> Error:  Error in recode(dat, pm25_rank = "PM2.5") :    unused argument
> (pm25_rank = "PM2.5")

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Note you need both `""` and `''`

```
test1<-recode(dat, " 'pm25_rank' = 'PM2.5' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip the association and do away with the string format on the left hand side.

```
library(dplyr)

recode(dat, pm25_rank = 'PM2.5')

# [1] "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5" "PM2.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `sub`

```
sub("pm(\\d)(\\d)_.*", "PM\\1.\\2", dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also recode with a named vector according to the documentation:

```
vec <- setNames(c('PM2.5'), c('pm25_rank'))

dplyr::recode(dat, !!!vec)
```

This could be handy if you have value-keys more readily available in your code so you don't have to type things out by hand.